# Can WM_HOTKEY be used to simulate hotkey events?

Tags: c++, winapi

In my program(C++, WinAPI), I wanted to simulate pressing some existing hotkeys set in other running programs. I know there is a [**SendInput**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function which simulates the keyboard input, but it seemed too much work as it needs to create a lot of structures for the keys.

I was trying use [**SendMessage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  or **PostMessage** with HWND_BROADCAST and WM_HOTKEY parameters. Neither worked.

The code looks like this:

```
WORD hotkey = MAKEWORD(MOD_CONTROL, VK_SPACE); // Ctrl + Space

SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST,
             WM_HOTKEY,
             (WPARAM)hotkey , 0);
```

Am I on the right track? or this should be done completely in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendInput is the best answer, honestly. This is because in the message loop your calls to the traslateaccellerator will look at the message , and in that message theres a bit flag on LPARAM, indicating what other keys are pressed with that key. You dont want to have to fill out that bit flag yourself, but .....  just in case you do .. and dont want to use SendInput...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx details how to do it. Of course, if you want to use an AcceleratorTable, thats easily done with a resource editor, just in your message loop, hook it up with this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646373%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for ur advise :) I'm still not familiar with the concept of the accelerators, I'll keep digging around in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use HWND_BROADCAST with something like WM_HOTKEY. In fact, avoid HWND_BROADCAST except in the circumstances when you really do want to broadcast a message to every single window. You are going to hit an unbelievable amount of trouble with other windows processing your message otherwise.

You are also using WM_HOTKEY wrong. wParam does not compose of a HIWORD/LOWORD of two keys. Programmers assign hotkeys with [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which they pass an identifier and also the hotkeys which generate a WM_HOTKEY message with that identifier.

There are several ways for you to find this identifier which should be what your wParam is. First off you could debug the target and breakpoint on RegisterHotKey() till you find the one you want. Alternatively you could use Spy++ and target the window and check what the identifier is.

There is of course the possibility the hotkey is not working via a hotkey but instead something like a keyboard accelerator. You would need to follow similar steps to find the parameters are to the WM_COMMAND or WM_SYSCOMMAND that is received by the target when you press that button. My recommendation is to go with Spy++.

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting, the hotkey should be in lParam in terms of WM_HOTKEY message. For wParam, Ill give Spy++ a go. Now for the handle...if I don't use HWND_BROADCAST, how do I get the specific handle to another program? will Spy++ help me in this too?

Comment: You can use FindWindow to get a window handle from a class name or window name or both. There are also other ways such as EnumWindows.